# Confusion with (notation in) a surface integral problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I encountered the following problem in a practice Advanced Calc exam, and I have an issue.

> Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is a strictly positive function satisfying $|\nabla\phi|^2=4\phi$ and $\Delta(\phi^2)=20\phi$. Evaluate $$\int_S\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}ds,$$ where $S$ is the surface of the unit sphere centered at the origin, $\cfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}$ is the directional derivative of the unit outward notmal to $S$, and $ds$ is the surface measure of $S$.

I cannot for the life of me recall what the $\Delta$ means in this context. Can someone help me out?

Note that I am not (at present) looking for any hints or help in evaluating the integral, though I will update this post later if I'm still stymied even after having this notation issue cleared up.

Comment: Maybe it is the Laplacian $$\Delta  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial x_k^2}}} $$

Comment: For $$\Bbb R^2$$ is is $$\Delta f = {\nabla ^2}f = \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {y^2}}}$$
For $$\Bbb R^3$$ is is $$\Delta f = {\nabla ^2}f = \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {y^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {z^2}}}$$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I followed the initial comment, but thanks for making sure!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: That turned out to be exactly what was needed. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll accept it, and we can put this thing to bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the Laplacian Operator

$$\Delta  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial x_k^2}}}$$

For two dimesions, you'd get

$$\Delta f = {\nabla ^2}f = \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {y^2}}}$$

For three,

$$\Delta f = {\nabla ^2}f = \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {x^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {y^2}}} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}f}}{{\partial {z^2}}}$$ and so on.